# Debugging a Sums of Digit Factorials

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I would to solve this problem illustrated in this image using C++

> Define f(n) as the sum of the factorials of the digits of n. For example, f(342) = 3! + 4! + 2! = 32.
>
> Define sf(n) as the sum of the digits of f(n). So sf(342) = 3 + 2 = 5.
>
> Define g(i) to be the smallest positive integer n such that sf(n) = i. Though sf(342) is 5, sf(25) is also 5, and it can be verified that g(5) is 25.
>
> Define sg(i) as the sum of the digits of g(i). So sg(5) = 2 + 5 = 7.
>
> Further, it can be verified that g(20) is 267 and ∑ sg(i) for 1 ≤ i ≤ 20 is 156.
>
> What is ∑ sg(i) for 1 ≤ i ≤ 150?

Image:

[image]

Here is my approach. My code takes long time running, and it works

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int factorial(int n);
std::vector<int> int_to_vector(int n);
int sum_vector(std::vector<int> v);
int get_smallest_number(std::vector<int> v, int sum, int n);
int sum_sg(int n )


int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    int q;
    int m,n;
    int g;
    int sum = 0;
    std::vector<int> vec;
    
    cin>>q;
    if( 1<=q && q<=100000){
        
    std::vector<int> s;
    int fact = 0;
    int sg = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < q; i++){
        
       cin>>n>>m;
       fact = factorial(n);
       s = int_to_vector(fact);
       sum = sum_vector(s);
       g = get_smallest_number(s, sum, n);
       s = int_to_vector(g);
       sum = sum_vector(s);
    
    }
    
    }
    
       
    return 0;
}

int factorial(int n){
 
 if (n==0) return 1;
 return factorial(n-1)*n;     
}

std::vector<int> int_to_vector(int n){
    
    std::vector<int> numbers;
     while(n>0)
    {
         numbers.push_back(n%10);
         n/=10;
    }
    return numbers;
}

int sum_vector(std::vector<int> v){
    
    int sum=0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        
        sum+=v.at(i);
    }
    
    return sum;  
}

int get_smallest_number(std::vector<int> v, int sum, int n){
    
    int i = 0;
    int factoriel = 1;
    std::vector<int> vect;
    int sum2 = 0;
    
    
while( i < n){
    
    factoriel = factorial(i);
    vect = int_to_vector(factoriel);
    sum2 = sum_vector(vect);
    
    if( sum2 == sum) return i;
    
    i++ ;
}

return n;
    
}
```

I think on recursive solutions, but it seems somehow more complex to implement. Are there any solutions using modern C++ and STL?

Comment: don't pass vectors by value when you can pass a (const) reference

Comment: I see nothing in the code that computes *"the sum of the factorials of the digits"*. So that's where you need to start. Write a function that can compute `f(342)` and return the value `32`.

Comment: Using a recursive function to compute a factorial is slow. A simple loop would be faster. And since you only need the factorial for single digits, a lookup table would be even faster, e.g. `int factorials[10] = {1,1,2,6,24,120,...`

Comment: user3386109, if you look well in the code, I try to compute the factorial fact, the I convert the result into vector<int> where its values are the digits of fact, after that I sum up all values of the vector so that I get sf(n) ( sum of digit of factorial (n) )

Answer (score 0):

Here is below a bad solution with less complexity, please any suggestion to have good and fast code rather than this below,

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
std::vector<int> factorial {1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880};
std::vector<int> int_to_vector(int n);
int sum_vector(std::vector<int> v);
int find_g(int i);
int calculat_sum_fact(std::vector<int> v);

int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    int m,n,q;
    std::vector<int> vec;
    std::vector<int> s;
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    cin>>q; 
    
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++){
    cin>>n>>m;
    numbers.push_back(n);
   // cout<< numbers.at(i);
    }
    
    for(int k = 0; k < numbers.size(); k++){
        
        int sum = 0;
       
       for (int i = 0; i < numbers.at(k)+1; i++){
           
           s = int_to_vector(find_g(i));
           sum += sum_vector(s);
       }
        cout <<  sum << "\n";
          
    }     
    return 0;
}


std::vector<int> int_to_vector(int n){
    
    std::vector<int> numbers;
     while(n>0)
    {
         numbers.push_back(n%10);
         n/=10;
    }
    return numbers;
}

int sum_vector(std::vector<int> v){
    
     int sum=0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        
        sum+=v.at(i);
    }
    
    return sum;  
}


int find_g(int i){
    
    std::vector<int> s ;
    int sum = 0;
    int j = 0;
    
        //cout<<"sf 1= " << j << endl;
    
    while(true){
        
        s = int_to_vector(j);
        sum = calculat_sum_fact(s);
        s= int_to_vector(sum);
        sum = sum_vector(s);
            //cout<<"sf 2= " << j << endl;
        
        
        if (sum == i) {
            
            //cout<<"sf = " << j << endl;
            return j;
            
           //break;
            
        }
        //cout<<"sf = " << j << endl;
        j++; 
          
    }
}

int calculat_sum_fact(std::vector<int> v){
    
    int sum = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ ){
        
        
        sum += factorial.at(v.at(i));
        
    }
    
    
    
    return sum;
}
```